# Haskell: is it possible to output type as a part of a program?

Tags: debugging, haskell, types

To help with debugging and writing programs in Haskell, I am thinking about ability of Haskell programs to output types of variables as part of the program. For example, I have following code:

```
listHEADFiles :: ReaderT LgRepo IO ()
listHEADFiles = do
  ref <- resolveReference $ T.pack "HEAD"
  case ref of 
    Nothing -> fail "Could not resolve reference named 'HEAD'"
    Just reference -> do
      obj <- lookupObject reference
      case obj of 
        CommitObj commit -> do
          objects <- listAllObjects Nothing (commitOid commit)
          for_ objects (\case 
            TreeObjOid toOid -> do
              tree <- lookupTree toOid
              treeEntries <- sourceTreeEntries tree
              entries <- lift $ treeEntries
              outputTypeOf entries
            )
        _ -> fail "'HEAD' is not a commit object"
```

I want to output type of variable `entries` because I fail to understand what exactly happens after I lift the value. I can go to documentation, but it always perplexes me to calculate it by hand. I would like to know for sure what type it is when my program is executed. In other words, I want functionality of `:t` in `ghci` as a part of my program. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really want your program to output a type: you want the compiler to output a type when it compiles your program. The feature you're looking for is [Partial type signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/partial-type-signatures.html). The idea is you put an incomplete signature on an expression, and you get out a compiler "error" telling you how to fill in the blanks. If you have no idea at all of the type, an acceptable incomplete signature would be just `_`:

```
(entries :: _) <- lift $ treeEntries
```